# Calling pure member function of initonly data in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

When calling function that does not modifies data, it still reports warning "member function will be invoked on a copy of the initonly data member". Function I am calling is virtual override of ToString.

```
public value struct A
{
virtual System::String^ ToString() override { return "a"; }
};

public value struct B
{
initonly A a;
virtual System::String^ ToString() override { return a.ToString(); }  // <-- warning and copy of a is created
};
```

How do I prevent creation of copy and make it call ToString directly on 'a'?

Comment: @Hans: Not a duplicate; in this question he controls the code being called.

Comment: Some testing shows that the CLR allows using the instance directly, but it makes the code unverifiable.  Would be nice if the C++/CLI compiler would allow creation of a `const A%` to an initonly field (except of course when `/clr:safe` is in effect)... but it doesn't.